# Why are some Callers not displaying in the Show Related Items list (Xcode)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, refactoring, compiler-warnings, shortcut

I'm refactoring some existing code (Objective-C) and I want to find all the references of a deprecated function in Xcode (9.2). To do this, I'm clicking on the "Show Related Items" menu, selecting "Callers." For this function, the Callers options is greyed out. However, I can do a text-search on this function name and find that it is, in fact, being referenced.

What would cause an implementation of a function to be hidden from the Callers list?

### The callee function:

```
- (NSString *) createWifiUser: (NSString *) inuser:(NSString *)inpassword:(NSString *)inaccountid

{
    //returns xml
}
```

### The caller:

```
self.wsret= [[fpws createWifiUser:wifiname.text :wifipass.text :sharedManager.accountId ] mutableCopy];
```

### The greyed out Callers menu:

[image]

### Additional Note

I wonder if this is related to the warnings the IDE is displaying about the function parameter syntax:

'inuser' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector

'inpassword' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this issue is, in fact, caused by the unnamed parameters. I refactored the function to use named parameters:

```
- (NSString *)createWifiUser:(NSString *)inuser inpassword:(NSString *)inpassword inaccountid:(NSString *)inaccountid
{
    //return xml
}
```

I also refactored the caller to use the named parameters:

```
self.wsret= [[fpws createWifiUser:wifiname.text inpassword:wifipass.text inaccountid:sharedManager.accountId ] mutableCopy];
```

The warnings disappeared. And the caller now shows up in the Show Related Items menu.
[image]

Documentation from Apple regarding unnamed parameters:
[Naming Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1001751-BCIJHEDH)

> Use keywords before all arguments.